# ASUS UM3402YAR speakers not working on fedora linux

Tags: fedora

Ever since i've installed linux on this laptop in can't manage to have the speakers working. In the arch linux wiki there is a solution linked, which refers to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/masselstine/8fe9634b4c31cef07b8dfab089e4eb38) but i can't manage to reproduce the steps on my fedora linux.

For example the vmlinuz is not showing on the grub boot menu and i don't really know how to operate, can someone guide me through the steps?